# I'm trying to create an emoji out of an image with create_custom_emoji and I'm getting a 'issing 1 required positional argument: 'self''

Tags: python, discord.py, self

```
@bot.command()
async def createemoji(ctx):
    with open('Racoon.jpg', 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
        await discord.Guild.create_custom_emoji(name='Raccoon', image=data)
```

This is the code, the image file is in the directory of the main.py.
This is the full error:

```
Ignoring exception in command createemoji:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\imnap\Interpreter\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, 
in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\imnap\PycharmProjects\Cyrene\main.py", line 235, in createemoji
    await discord.Guild.create_custom_emoji(name='Raccoon', image=data)
TypeError: create_custom_emoji() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\imnap\Interpreter\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, 
in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\imnap\Interpreter\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, 
in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\imnap\Interpreter\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, 
in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 
create_custom_emoji() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I've looked up dozens of posts very similar to mine, but most of them aren't to do with discord.py. I've looked up the documention and it should be formatted exactly as needed. Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm at a loss as to the issue.

Comment: Do you know what a *method* is? When you write `discord.Guild.create_custom_emoji`, for *which guild* do you expect it to create a custom emoji? Also, what happened when you tried reading the documentation for `create_custom_emoji` and looking at the example code? What happened when you tried putting `discord.Guild.create_custom_emoji` into a search engine?

Comment: To be honest I didn't think about googling the piece of code myself and I almost insantly got what I was looking for. I was spinning my wheels for hours looking in the wrong place. Woops.

Comment: What *did* you look for? You should at least try to look for *something*, and generally start with the simplest thing. Stack Overflow [is a last resort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to create the emoji to the class discord.Guild

What you realy want to do, is to add the emote to the guild the command is used in

```py
@bot.command()
async def createemoji(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    with open('Racoon.jpg', 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
        await guild.create_custom_emoji(name='Raccoon', image=data)
```